# SQL group by 2 fields

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I got that table :

```
id, user_a, user_b, score
1,       3,      7,   19
2,       8,      3,   20
3,       3,      2,   10
4,       7,      6,   2
5,       3,      6,   7
```

I achieve counting the number of match per user with :

```
select user, count(*)
from
(
    select user_a as user from tablename
    union all
    select user_b from tablename
) dt
group by user
```

I now want to add user email from usertable:

```
COUNT(*), user,  email
4,       3,      user3@mail.com
2,       7,      user7@mail.com
1,       8,      user8@mail.com
1,       2,      user2@mail.com
2,       6,      user6@mail.com
```

I 've tried this :

```
SELECT user, count(*) 
FROM ( 
SELECT user_a AS user, ut.email
   FROM tablename
   UNION ALL 
      SELECT user_b
      FROM tablename
) dt 
WHERE user IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN usertable ut ON ut.id = user
GROUP BY user
```

but there is a syntax error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN usertable ut ON ut.id = user
GROUP BY user'
```

Any idea ?

Comment: @Jens Most of the time, l would have to agree with you, but surely in this instance it's completely obvious!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `UNION ALL` in a derived table, to get one column of users. `GROUP BY` it's result.

```
select user, count(*)
from
(
    select user_a as user from tablename
    union all
    select user_b from tablename
) dt
group by user
```

Answer to updated question:

```
SELECT dt.user, ut.email, count(*) 
FROM
( 
    SELECT user_a AS user FROM tablename
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT user_b FROM tablename
) dt 
LEFT JOIN usertable ut ON ut.id = dt.user
GROUP BY dt.user, ut.email
```

Comment: Great ! :) Thanks a lot ! .. imagine now I want user email from user table .. I tried a LEFT JOIN  (LEFT JOIN user_table u ON u.id = user) AND SELECT u.email but an error occurred ! .. any idea ? complete query : SELECT user, u.email, count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT user_a as user
    FROM battle 
    UNION ALL 
     SELECT user_b
     FROM battle
) dt 
WHERE user IS NOT NULL 
LEFT JOIN usertable u ON u.id = user
GROUP BY user

Comment: @Flo, please, start another question!

Comment: @Flo, add the new question's expected result. (I can't figure it out.)